# Pandas, como buscar en columna todos los valores exactos contenidos en una lista

Tags: python, pandas

Primero necesito saber como buscar en la columna (Name) si contiene "todos" los valores que tengo guardado en una lista y me devuelva  TRUE o FALSE si contiene exactamente el contenido de valores de la lista.
Una vez que sepa como hacerlo, tengo un par de combinaciones de valores en listas los cuales necesito corroborar
Ejemplo:

De la columna Name necesito  buscar si esta columna contiene "exactamente todos los valores" de algunas de estas posibles combinaciones `list1=[´L11','N11','M11','F11','B11']`,  `list2 =[´L11','N11','M11','F11']`, `list3= [´L11','N11','M11']`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La combinación  del ejemplo sería `list1=[´L11','N11','M11','F11','B11']` que debe dar TRUE ya que la columna->Name "SI" contiene exactamente lo que tengo en list1  y las demás listas si busco me deberían dar  FALSE.

En este ejemplo2 la combinación que debería dar TRUE seria `list3= [´L11','N11','M11']`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es saber como realizar esta búsqueda en la columna para luego hacer una función, aplicarla sobre el df y todas las listas (list1/list2/list3), y así poder determinar según que lista me da TRUE el tipo de datos con el que estoy trabajando.

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Comment: No lo entiendo bien, pero sospecho que lo que quieres hacer requeriría usar la función [`str.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) en vez de `str.contains()`. Y probablemente `.all()` en vez de `.any()` pero ya digo que no se entiende del todo el objetivo.

Comment: desde ya gracias por responder @abulafia, edite la consulta para ejemplificar un poco mejor la idea, saludos y gracias nuevamente...

Comment: He puesto una respuesta que creo que es lo que buscas, pero hay una cosa que no entiendo. En tu ejemplo `list1` contiene todos los elementos de `list2` y de `list3`, por lo que si la columna te da TRUE para `list1`, también te lo daría para las otras dos listas (pues también ellas tendrán _todos_ sus elementos en esa columna). No veo forma de que pueda dar TRUE para `list1` pero FALSE para las otras dos. Lo que si puedes hacer es que en cuanto te dé TRUE para una lista, no seguir comprobando las restantes.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @abulafia, es correcto lo que comentas "por lo que si la columna te da TRUE para list1, también te lo daría para las otras dos listas (pues también ellas tendrán todos sus elementos en esa columna)", pero  necesito que además de  coincidir  en los valores contenidos en la lista, también respete la "cantidad de elementos" que contiene la lista, porque sino, todos me darán TRUE siempre en el caso que la columna contenga por ejemplo todos los valores como es  list1 que es justamente lo que comentas, seguiré investigando desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo, saludos

Comment: Sigo sin entender. A qué te refieres con "respetar la cantidad de elementos"? Si haces el test de si contiene por ejemplo `lista3`, te dirá True, pues contiene TODOS los elementos de `lista3` (que son 3). Aunque si hubieras hecho el test con `list1` también te habría dado True, pues contiene también TODOS los de `list1`. Creo que la solución a esto es tener tus listas ordenadas de más a menos elementos y abandonar el bucle tan pronto como una te dé `True`

Comment: gracias @abulafia  hice lo  que propusiste de realizar un break cuando se cumple la condición y funciona para lo que estaba necesitando... gracias nuevamente, saludos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la forma más simple es usar conjuntos. Convierte `lista1`, `lista2`, `lista3` en un conjunto y mira si es subconjunto de lo que hay en `df.name`.

Por ejemplo, creo el siguiente dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['M14', 'F15', 'B15', 'B12', 'B14', 'N11', 'F12', 'M12', 'B13', 'M15', 'M11', 'F13', 'L11', 'F14', 'M13']})
```

que sería:

```
  name
0   M14
1   F15
2   B15
3   B12
4   B14
5   N11
6   F12
7   M12
8   B13
9   M15
10  M11
11  F13
12  L11
13  F14
14  M13
```

El siguiente bucle miraría si esa columna contiene o no todos los elementos de cada una de las listas que te interesan:

```
list1 = ['L11','N11','M11','F11','B11']
list2 = ['L11','N11','M11','F11']
list3 = ['L11','N11','M11']

listas = [list1, list2, list3]
for i, lista in enumerate(listas, start=1):
    coincide = set(lista).issubset(df.name)
    print(f"list{i}: {coincide}")
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

```
list1: False
list2: False
list3: True
```